# Shakin' things up

Tags: c#, windows, windows-7, windows-vista, shake

I have a little app here, and I would love to be able to do my own stuff in Vista/Win7 when I shake the form.

Currently, when a form is shaken, it will restore/minimize everything else. But I want to change that behavior in my app only. So when my form is shaken, I could, for example, shuffle the playlist, or Clear the contents of a Canvas etc...

Is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: when you mean shake, you mean you grab the form and literally 'shake' the mouse to produce erratic position behavior of the form?

Comment: Yes sir, you're spot on! That's a standard feature in Vista/Win7

Comment: It is? I use Vista and I've never seen that. How do you access this programmatically, or are you asking how to do this?

Comment: Still an XP user ;)  Interesting problem.  I think i'd google "c# detect form shake".  Found this link actually: http://www.vcskicks.com/aero-shake.php

Comment: Looks likes it's a Windows 7 feature that may be available in updates to Vista - I definitely don't have it. But it's a cool idea, definitely, and doesn't look too hard to implement.

Comment: Yeah. I have Vista Home Premium, and Windows 7 Home Premium, and they both have the shakey thing goin'on.

Comment: Thank you for the link, Robb. Works perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another link with working example:

[aero-shake](http://www.vcskicks.com/aero-shake.php)

And yes pretty cool feature.

Comment: I can finally port Shake-The-Baby to Windows! </TASTELESS>

Answer (score 3):

If you're asking for a code sample that does this, here you go:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/aero-shake.aspx

Just replace the part that minimizes and maximizes other windows with whatever else you want to do.

Personally, I think this is pretty cool, and I'm seriously trying to fight the urge to use this everywhere, now.  My ideal of the perfect user interface has always been a form with just one button on it.  With shaking, I wouldn't even need the button.

Comment: +1 for being in total agreement: fighting the urge to use it everywhere :)

Comment: Yeah. I love this new shake feature, it's so awesome! With a big imagination, and the know-how, I bet we could come up with a program that lets you shake to perform more than one action, without the use of buttons

Comment: Go for it. The linked code samples all use a pretty crude algorithm for detecting shaking, which could definitely be improved. Detecting left-to-right shaking vs. up-and-down would be pretty fun to do. It makes total sense to use this for clearing a drawing program, too, as you suggested - just like an Etch-a-Sketch.

Comment: Yeah! That's what they're called! I was going to mention Etch-A-Sketch in my question but couldn't remember what they're called

Comment: Thanks, but I think you should definitely leave the check with Robb's answer. I only found my link by googling something I found in his.